# EOL while scanning string literal, file won't run

Tags: python, string

I've checked it over 30 times, I have no clue what's wrong with the string. It must be something minor that I just can't see.

```
#Description

print("Costs of EMS responses")

Print("Choose the costs of providing Emergency Medical Services \
     + \n to your region. Remember, half will be covered by insurance \
     + \n of the patient then the rest will have to be paid out of pocket \
     + \n by the patient himself/herself.
")

#Variables

als = int(input("Advanced Life Support: "))
bls = int(input("Basic Life Support: "))
fireresponse = int(input("Fire Response: "))
aeromedical = int(input("EMS Helicopter: "))
citypolice = int(input("City Police: "))
statepolice = int(input("State Police: "))
countypolice = int(input("County Police: "))
swat = int(input("SWAT Team: "))
total = als + bls + fireresponse + aeromedical + citypolice + statepolice + countypolice + swat

print("\nCombined amount of costs from services in the region: ", total)

input("\n\n\nPress enter to exit menu)
```

Comment: Line 5: Why capital P in Print?

Comment: Rather than the ugly line continuations, consider mutliline strings and `textwrap.dedent` (see e.g. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/60369/32391).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the first one that I see:

```
input("\n\n\nPress enter to exit menu)
```

And the second one is that you forgot to escape the newline in code at the end of this line:

```
 + \n by the patient himself/herself.
```

Comment: Edited that and the capitalized P in print. It's highlighting mainly the things below variable but I cease to see the problem with those. It's highlighting the words in parenthesis after "int(input("... although I don't see how it's done wrong. I'm currently learning from a book and that's exactly how it's written there..

Comment: Yup, those were it. Not sure why it was highlighting different things. I appreciate your help!

Comment: @Pythonhelper: You forgot to close the string on the last line.